# Yii framework: how to check whether checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, yii

I want always show additional fields when chceckbox is unchecked and always hide when is checked.

I have **checkbox:**

```
<?php echo $form->checkBox($model2, 'ignore', array('onChange'=>'javascript:toggleUser2()')); ?>
```

**js script:**

```
<script>
                    function toggleUser2() {
                        if($('.User2_ignore').is(':checked')) {
                            $('.user2').hide();
                        } else {
                            $('.user2').show();
                        }
                    }
                    toggleUser2();
                </script>
```

This always return false:

```
 console.log($('.User2_ignore').is(':checked'));
```

I also tried attr('checked') and val(), but they are returnig 'undefined'. Is there any way to check checkbox is checked or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using this Jquery Code as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            alert("Checked");
             //$(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("checked");
           }else{
            alert("Unchecked")  
           }
        });

});
```